# Is there a depthwise constant convolutional layer option in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm interested in applying a convolutional kernel that's only got HxW parameters where (H, W) is kernel size. The kernel would still have dimensions CxHxW like a normal convolution, but the parameters are constant in the channel dimension.

Is there an inbuilt option for this in PyTorch?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377831/what-would-happen-if-cnn-reused-same-kernel-weights-for-each-channel

Comment: @Ivan no it doesn't. I know what I want to do (I'm not asking for advice on whether this is a sensible thing to do). Just looking for a potential option which will allow it without me having to make a custom layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be equivalent to a convolution kernel with a 1-dimensional (summed) input. You can verify that mathematically (just factor out the weight). We can also verify it with code, so you can use this if you really wanted to do that.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Normal conv
normal_conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 2, kernel_size=1)

# We can artificially repeat the weight along the channel dimension -> constant depthwise
repeated_conv = nn.Conv2d(6, 2, kernel_size=1)
repeated_conv.weight.data = normal_conv.weight.data.expand(-1, 6, -1, -1)
repeated_conv.bias.data = normal_conv.bias.data

data = torch.randn(1, 6, 3, 3)

# same result
print(repeated_conv(data))
print(normal_conv(data.sum(1, keepdim=True)))
```

So, you don't need a custom layer. Just create a convolution with the number of input channels = 1, and sum the input in the channel dimension before you feed it into the layer.

UPDATE: Backward pass testing:

```py
data1 = torch.randn(1, 6, 3, 3)
data2 = data1.clone()
data1.requires_grad = True
data2.requires_grad = True

repeated_conv(data1).mean().backward()
normal_conv(data2.sum(1, keepdim=True)).mean().backward()

print(data1.grad, repeated_conv.weight.grad.sum(1))
print(data2.grad, normal_conv.weight.grad)
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work as intended in the backward pass?

Comment: @Ivan If the math is the same, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Just do a backward pass with `data` as input with `repeated_conv` and `normal_conv` you will get different gradients. The 6 layers are copied from the unique layer in `normal_conv` but the activations seem to be separate. So you're better off using the one-layer Conv1d with the summed input.

Comment: @Ivan I am not sure if I have understood you correctly. I tested the backward pass and the gradients (to both data and parameter) look ok to me. Is there something that I missed?

Comment: Oops my bad, gradient will be the same. However you won't be able to update the single layer model with that `repeated_conv` model since it will have a 6-layer gradient. Try initializing a `torch.optim` on it and call `.step()`, it will raise a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: Wow I feel silly now... I solved it by permuting dims (width swapped with channels) and applying a single column convolution. And I thought I was being clever. Sometimes you forget it's just sums and products

Comment: Now that I think of it though... What I just said is not the same. But on the other hand it is what I wanted (that is, to not sum over channels, but keep the channel dim) I just realised my question was poorly posed.

Comment: @Ivan I meant to use `sum`+`normal_conv` in the actual implementation. `repeated_conv` is only there to verify that the two are equivalent.